# Why is my music not playing in reverse when using the property canPlayReverse in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer

Im trying to play my music in reverse by using the `canPlayReverse` property but that is not working. When I try to play it in reverse it goes forward. Here is the code I have below: Thank you!

```
class GameScene: SKScene, MPMediaPickerControllerDelegate, AVAudioPlayerDelegate {

private var player:AVPlayer! = AVPlayer()

override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

for touch in touches {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        let node = self.nodeAtPoint(location)


        //this is for the left turntable
        if node.name == "lefttt"  {

            //lets user rotate left turntable when there is one finger on turntable.
            let dy = leftTurntable.position.y - location.y
            let dx = leftTurntable.position.x - location.x
            let angle2 = atan2(dy, dx)
            leftTurntable.zRotation = angle2


            let delta = (angle2 - previousAngle); M_PI
            if delta > 0 {
                print("rotateleft")
                if musicPlayer == player.currentItem?.canPlayReverse {
                    musicPlayer.rate = -1.0

                }

            } else {

                print("rotateright")
                musicPlayer.rate = 3.0
                musicPlayer.play()
            }

            previousAngle = angle2
   }
```

Comment: If you're not getting "unexpectedly found nil" anymore and not crashing, you should probably fix the question so it makes sense to whoever reads it next.  :)

Answer (score 1):

When you use `asset!`, you're telling the compiler that the variable will point to a valid object but your code isn't setting `asset` to anything non-nil.

In general, avoid '!' whenever possible and test your optionals instead.

Comment: I changed my code and dont get the error anymore but when I try to reverse the music thats playing it goes forward instead. Can you take a look at my code? I updated it in the op.

Comment: Do you actually get to the line that sets the rate to -1?

Comment: This: `musicPlayer == player.currentItem?.canPlayReverse` ...doesn't make sense to me.  How is `musicPlayer` defined?  What's the difference between `musicPlayer` and `player`?

Comment: musicPlayer is an AVAudioPlayer and player is an AVPlayer.

Comment: I'm surprised it lets you test whether an `AVAudioPlayer` object is equal to a `Bool` value.

Comment: What do you see if you print `musicPlayer` and `player.currentItem` just before you compare?

Comment: I get nil for player.currentItem and <AVAudioPlayer: 0x159094d90> for musicPlayer

Comment: I was wondering if you had any suggestions on how to make this work. Thanks!

Comment: Not really but, if your player has no currentItem, anything it tells you about `canPlayReverse` is unreliable at best.  I assume you need to set up `player` correctly before anything else starts making sense.  How you do that depends on what item it's supposed to be playing.

Comment: I tried using 'AVPlayer' but it doesnt work as good as 'AVAudioPlayer'